# Django DRF use same URL pattern for different views

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

In Django Rest Framework, I have two separate views for the same model. I would like to use the same url pattern to access both views, and differentiate between the two based on the method that is used. So I have something like:

```
class MyObjectListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    pass


class MyObjectCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    pass
```

Both views obviously would have different logic. The url pattern for both would be `'myObjects\'`, and depending on the method that is used (`GET`  or `POST`), it would need to refer to the appropriate view (`MyObjectListAPIView` or `MyObjectCreateAPIView` respectively). Is there a way to achieve this (without reverting to plain Django and losing the functionality of DRF)?

Comment: That is typically done in a `ViewSet`.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem thanks for the pointer but could you please elaborate just a little bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

The out-of-the-box way to achieve this is with `ViewSets`, specifically the `ModelViewSet`, in conjunction with the default `ModelSerializer` and DRF's built-in `DefaultRouter`. It would look like the below:

```py
## views.py ##
from rest_framework import viewsets

from myapp.models import MyModel
from myapp.serializers import MyModelSerializer

class MyObjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer


## urls.py ##
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from .views import MyObjectViewSet

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'myObjects', MyObjectViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Note, this will achieve what you want, i.e. same endpoint *'myObjects/'* with different logic based on HTTP Method *(GET -> List, POST -> Create)* -- BUT note that it will also do more than just this, as you will also get the associated *Retrieve/Update/Delete* functionality at the endpoint *'myObjects/<pk>/'*.

---

**Longer Answer:**

If you want to avoid `ViewSets` for any particular reason, you would just use the `GenericAPIView` with the `ListModelMixin` and `CreateModelMixin` as well. This could look something like the below:

```py
## views.py ##
from rest_framework import generics, mixins
from myapp.models import MyModel
from myapp.serializers import MyModelSerializer

class MyObjectListCreateAPIView(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                                mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                                generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Then simply register it to your URLs file as you normally would for any Class-Based View, with no need for the Router here; e.g. like the below:

```py
## urls.py ##
from django.urls import path

from .views import MyObjectListCreateAPIView

urlpatterns = [
    # ..any other url patterns.. #
    path('myObjects/', MyObjectListCreateAPIView.as_view())
]
```

This should satisfy your constraints exactly, without the additional features the `ViewSet` offers.

The official **DRF** docs do a very good step-by-step tutorial on how to move from 'APIView' to 'GenericViews' plus 'Mixins', all the way through to 'ViewSets with Routers', and the docs are pretty comprehensive. I recommend taking a look at it [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/) if you haven't already.